# Which are the good ways to apologize?

Tags: phrase-usage, politeness

Which are the good ways to apologize to friends, boss and relatives?

Consider some situations like:

1. I was tired last night and I got mad at my friend.  On the next day he asked me something. What could I say? I wanted to say sorry.
2. How to apologize to my boss when I am late in office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep it fairly informal and to make sure to use the word "sorry" without qualification.

1) I was tired last night and i got mad at my friend. On the next day he asked me some thing. What could i say.I want to say sorry.

> I'm sorry I got mad last night, I was tired.
>
> Sorry I got mad. I was just tired.

2) How to apologize to my boss when i am late in office?

> I'm sorry I'm late. It won't happen again.

Spoke apologies are almost always very informal. Written apologies tend to be much more formal, like:

> Please accept my sincere apology for arriving late at the office yesterday.